# Mule HTTP listener query in Groovy?

Tags: http, groovy, mule, connector

I have a Mule application with many flows and HTTP endpoints, and a Groovy script that needs to invoke some of them. Is there a way I can retrieve a list of registered HTTP endpoints so as to build the proper URLs to get the host and port associated with a particular service?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was easier than it sounded:

```
ep = muleContext.getRegistry().getEndpoints()
ep.each 
{ 
    if (it.getEndpointURI().toString().contains("---service name---"))
    . . . 
}
```